# Why can Necessitas not support to display Chinese characters in my qt application for android?

Tags: android, qt

Necessitas is the codename for the port of Qt on the Android Operating System and of the user-friendly Qt Creator Integration with Android. Now , using Necessitas (QT for Android),I can run & debug my Qt Applications on Android Devices.
But I got these log when I want to setText("中文") on QLabel.
Why  can Necessitas not support to display Chinese characters in my qt application for android ? Or, what steps do I have less ?

```
Starting remote process ...
I/Qt JAVA (  469): surfaceChanged: 480,762
D/dalvikvm(  469): Trying to load lib /data/data/eu.licentia.necessitas.ministro/files/qt/lib/libQtCore.so 0x44ede7e8
D/dalvikvm(  469): Added shared lib /data/data/eu.licentia.necessitas.ministro/files/qt/lib/libQtCore.so 0x44ede7e8
D/dalvikvm(  469): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/eu.licentia.necessitas.ministro/files/qt/lib/libQtCore.so 0x44ede7e8, skipping init
D/dalvikvm(  469): Trying to load lib /data/data/eu.licentia.necessitas.ministro/files/qt/lib/libQtGui.so 0x44ede7e8
D/dalvikvm(  469): Added shared lib /data/data/eu.licentia.necessitas.ministro/files/qt/lib/libQtGui.so 0x44ede7e8
D/dalvikvm(  469): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/eu.licentia.necessitas.ministro/files/qt/lib/libQtGui.so 0x44ede7e8, skipping init
D/dalvikvm(  469): Trying to load lib /data/data/eu.licentia.necessitas.ministro/files/qt/plugins/platforms/android/libandroid-8.so 0x44ede7e8
D/dalvikvm(  469): Added shared lib /data/data/eu.licentia.necessitas.ministro/files/qt/plugins/platforms/android/libandroid-8.so 0x44ede7e8
I/Qt      (  469): qt start
D/dalvikvm(  469): Trying to load lib /data/data/eu.licentia.necessitas.industrius.example.Yiyaaixuexi/lib/libYiyaaixuexi.so 0x44ede7e8
D/dalvikvm(  469): Added shared lib /data/data/eu.licentia.necessitas.industrius.example.Yiyaaixuexi/lib/libYiyaaixuexi.so 0x44ede7e8
I/Qt      (  469): qt start
W/ApplicationContext(  469): Unable to create files directory
D/AndroidRuntime(  469): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(  469): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
E/AndroidRuntime(  469): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(  469): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(  469):    at eu.licentia.necessitas.industrius.QtActivity.startApplication(QtActivity.java:126)
E/AndroidRuntime(  469):    at eu.licentia.necessitas.industrius.QtActivity.access$000(QtActivity.java:62)
E/AndroidRuntime(  469):    at eu.licentia.necessitas.industrius.QtActivity$1$1.run(QtActivity.java:149)
E/AndroidRuntime(  469):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
E/AndroidRuntime(  469):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime(  469):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(  469):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
E/AndroidRuntime(  469):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(  469):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/AndroidRuntime(  469):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
E/AndroidRuntime(  469):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
E/AndroidRuntime(  469):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
I/Process (  469): Sending signal. PID: 469 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this question ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical ? Now I'm sure that it doesn't support at all.